# How to embed an external home page on a quasar/cordova/vue.js mobile app?

Tags: cordova, vue.js, mobile, phonegap, quasar-framework

I have a mobile app made in quasar/cordova/vue.js. I need to add a section where the user can browse a catalog available on the internet.

I managed to use the [inappbrowser plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html) however it opens the website full screen on top of my app. Can I make the browser fill a section of the app? So the bottom tab bar remains visible?

Comment: may be an iframe?

Comment: unfortunately the website i have to embed has a "same-origin" policy, so the iframe does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with inappbrowser, it's possible to open in webview a web page.

verify your config.xml, add if not present :

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: The inappbrowser is working, however the external web page is shown full screen, covering the app below. How can I make the inappbrowser fill a specific area on the app?

Comment: you can't use inappbrowser just for a specific area